# Problema al autenticar en WhatsApp Web con 'whatsapp-web.js' y 'puppeteer

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio, whatsapp-web

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Node.js que utiliza 'whatsapp-web.js' junto con 'puppeteer' para automatizar la autenticación en WhatsApp Web. Sin embargo, estoy enfrentando un problema específico durante este proceso y no puedo determinar su causa.

El problema se produce cuando ejecuto mi código para autenticar en WhatsApp Web. Después de escanear el código QR y completar la autenticación en la aplicación móvil de WhatsApp, el evento 'authenticated' de 'whatsapp-web.js' no se dispara, y no veo el mensaje console.log('Autenticado en WhatsApp Web'); en la terminal.

Aquí está el código relevante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola conseguiste la solucion? estoy pasando por lo mismo, trato de detectar tambien los eventos de desconectado, y de no autenticado y luego del codigo qr ningun evento se dispara.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que no definiste el evento 'ready'. Ese evento se dispara luego de que se valide el inicio de sesion con el QR.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready');
});
```

En caso de que ese evento no se dispare. Ahí está el problema. Estas usando la ultima version? Si es asi te sugiero que leas este foro:
[Foro Github](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2473)

Tambien te lo resumo, practicamente lo que tenes que hacer es verificar el archivo Client.js en la linea 175. Este mismo se encuentra en la carpeta de whatsapp-web.js en node_modules, deberia de ser este el directiorio

> /node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js

en el archivo Client.js buscar la constante `INTRO_IMG_SELECTOR`(que deberia de estar en la linea 175) luego de eso cambiarle el valor...Acá te adjunto lo que deberias de poner: `const INTRO_IMG_SELECTOR = 'div[role=\'textbox\']'; //'[data-icon=\'chat\']';`

Los motivos desconozco de porque hay que hacer tal cambio. Pero eso me funciono a mi. Espero que te haya ayudado. Saludos